# How to set up Umbraco cms in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, content-management-system, umbraco

Before download the cms Umbraco I want to know whether it is possible to set up the visual studio to work with umbraco? And if it is how?

Answer (score 5):

find here

http://blog.leekelleher.com/2008/08/20/setting-up-visual-studio-to-work-with-umbraco/

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/codegarden-2009/open-space-minutes/working-in-visual-studio-when-developing-umbraco-solutions

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [the setup in this blogpost](http://cultiv.nl/blog/2009/6/1/easily-debug-your-custom-umbraco-user-controls-in-visual-studio/). It's for VS2008, but it's basically the same as for VS2010.